# Python output not formatting correctly with output to LibreOffice by openpyxl

Tags: python, python-3.x, format, openpyxl

Attempting to format output to a LibreOffice calc (ie, linux-based Excel) document but the python format syntax isn't applied as expected.

Using the new string formatting, running the below:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A3'] = '{:>}'.format('rundate:')
ws['A4'] = '{:>}'.format('name:')
ws['A5'] = '{:>}'.format('comments:')

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Unexpectedly gives this, which appears to be left rather than right aligned:

[image]

Trying the left align char on the off chance I had them reversed:

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A3'] = '{:<}'.format('rundate:')
ws['A4'] = '{:<}'.format('name:')
ws['A5'] = '{:<}'.format('comments:')

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

Returns the same:

[image]

And another version (specifying total number of chars), makes it clear the text isn't being right aligned.  If anything, right aligned text should spill over the left side of the cell, not the right.

```
import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

ws['A3'] = '{:>12}'.format('rundate:')
ws['A4'] = '{:>12}'.format('name:')
ws['A5'] = '{:>12}'.format('comments:')

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

[image]

Comment: To the downvoter, what was the issue?

Answer (score 1):

From the [alignment](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/openpyxl.styles.alignment.html#openpyxl.styles.alignment.Alignment) module:

> Alignment options for use in styles.
>
> horizontal
> Value must be one of {‘left’, ‘centerContinuous’, ‘center’, ‘distributed’, ‘fill’, ‘justify’, ‘right’, ‘general’}

I think this will work:

```
from openpyxl.styles import Alignment
alignment=Alignment(horizontal='left')

import openpyxl as xl
wb = xl.Workbook()
ws = wb.active

for row in ws.iter_rows(min_col=1, max_col=1, min_row=3, max_row=5):
    for cell in row:
        cell.alignment = alignment

wb.save('test.xlsx')
```

or simply:

```py
ws['A3'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
ws['A4'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
ws['A5'].alignment = Alignment(horizontal='left')
```

Comment: Ugh, so janky...already needed two other sets of loops to format cells, this would be a cherry on top.  Try in a few, thanks.